# After editing macro code, the short cut to macro no longer works

Tags: excel, vba, keyboard, shortcut

Yesterday I asked for help with macro code.  I receive the help I needed and the code works great - with one exception - now, no matter what I do, the shortcut I used to use no longer works.

The keyboard shortcut was CTRL+q.  Now it doesn't work and nothing happens when I hit that keyboard combo.  I tried saving it with a different letter but that fails too.

Any ideas as to how to get the shortcut to work again?

Comment: What changes were made to the code yesterday? Did you rename the macro or create a new one?

Comment: i copied the code then deleted the macro, created a new macro doing virtually nothing then pasted in the old code and saved it using CRTL+q but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

From the **View** tab, select the **Macros** button and then **View Macros**. Look for your macro on the list that it displays, single-click it, then click the **Options...** button.

This shows you the dialog box you need. The shortcut key currently assigned to the macro (presumably none, based on your description) will be shown, and you can type whatever letter you would like. Don't forget that assigning a lower-case letter makes the shortcut ctrl-*letter* while using an upper-case letter makes it ctrl-shift-*letter*.

Comment: thank you, i will look at the macro this monday and let you know.